# How to write a glob in javascript to exclude and include the files?

Tags: javascript, glob

I wrote the following line of code which contains a glob for to exclude files from every folder:

```
 var images = gulp.src(['src/**/*.{png,svg,jpg,gif}', '!src/styles/images/abc/*.svg',
    '!src/styles/images/pqr/*card*.svg', '!src/styles/images/def/*.svg', '!src/styles/images/xyz/*.svg',
    '!src/styles/images/*-16.svg', '!src/styles/images/*[!16].svg', '!src/styles/images/svg-16/*.svg', 
    '!src/styles/images/uvw/*.png']).pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

As you can see that I am repeating `src/styles/images` almost everywhere. How can I further simplify this glob? Are there any other ways possible where we can make the repeated path common and add the rest?

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a `map` and concat arrays but honestly you should fix your actual folder structure.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I think so! I will do that too. Thanks a lot for giving me an idea to use map. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mapping is my idea for this problem

```
var src = ['src/**/*.{png,svg,jpg,gif}']
var stylesimages = [ 'abc/*.svg', 'pqr/*card*.svg', 'table/*.svg', 'xyz/*.svg', '*-16.svg', '*[!16].svg', 'svg-16/*.svg', 
    'uvw/*.png'].map(x => '!src/styles/images/' + x)

src = src.concat(stylesimages)

var images = gulp.src(src).pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helps. :)